# Pricing Strategy for Product that Ships Across a Country

Tags: competition

Not sure if this is the right place for this question.

Assume I produce a grocery item that I want to sell across the country. If I sell my product to a grocery nearby, my shipping cost will be less than if I were to sell the product to a grocery in some remote part of the country.

Assume further that the suggested retail price of this product should be about the same across the country, or it won't sell.

What's the proper way to handle a pricing strategy in this situation?

1. I sell the product at the same price to all groceries, but they have
   to pay for shipping. Then it's up to individual groceries how to
   price the product. If they were to follow the suggested retail
   price, groceries near the manufacturing plant would make more money
   than groceries further away from the manufacturing plant due to
   their higher cost of shipping.
2. I sell the product at the same price to all groceries and include
   the average shipping cost in my selling price. So, nearby grocery
   store would pay the same as remote grocery store. The risk would be
   if suddenly there is an abundance of orders from remote grocery
   stores -- and the included average shipping cost doesn't cover my
   shipping expenses.
3. I sell the product at the same price to all groceries and include
   the highest possible shipping cost in my selling price. Little risk
   to me and great for remote groceries, but nearby groceries are
   penalized.

Of course, the above options are an over simplification. For example, with regards to #3 - it's possible a competitor near my manufacturer could product a similar product at the same price point, then start selling to nearby groceries and only charge the shipping cost to that nearby grocery. Their product would then be the cheaper option and I would lose a customer.

What's a good strategy for the above scenario? What strategies did I miss?

Comment: 1. This seems like a business question without a specific framework and no possible definitive answer.

Comment: 2. What do you mean by "proper way"?

Comment: I guess "proper" would refer to whichever approach returns the best outcome. I'm thinking game theory.

Comment: I am sorry, but I think you may not know what game theory is.

Comment: Possibly. Open to any ideas and suggestions that could result in best outcome.

Comment: I don't think this is the right place for this question. If the question is about how differences in prices for the same product at different locations can arise (or *do* arise), it would be relevant here. If the question is about how *you* can price your products, it is not relevant here. It is not businessadvice.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @user253751  I judge this to be on-topic since economic considerations can be relevant to pricing strategy (albeit other considerations may also be relevant).  I don't think a request for business advice is necessarily off-topic, though many such requests would be.

Comment: Have you considered hiring a distribution company whose job is to do this?

Comment: @EconomicsNewbie what would be best outcome here would depend on the parameters. With the current set up the answer would be just it depends. For example, to provide at least some slightly less vague answer one would have to at least know what’s the market structure here so the situation can be set up as an IO problem or some more info so it can be turned into game. But even there without actually putting some value on model parameters you probably won’t get definitive answer...